# import error when using spafe library for feature extraction

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, feature-extraction

I ' am working on audio file and need to use spafe library for lfcc, lpc... and i install the library as mentionned in the site : https://spafe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But when i try to extract some features , like lfcc, mfcc, lpc, i have import error par example when i use this code :

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

import spafe.utils.vis as vis

from spafe.features.mfcc import lfcc
```

i have this error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'lfcc'
```

I don't undestand because i can import spafe, i have all dependancies the libraries required with the correct versions ( numpy, scipy...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the [docs example](https://spafe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/lfcc.html) (which I guess tou are trying to follow); it should be

```
from spafe.features.lfcc import lfcc
```

i.e. `lfcc`, not `mfcc` (which `mfcc` indeed does not have a module `lfcc`, hence the error).

Comment: thank you. i don't see it. but when i aply this code :

Comment: audio_path = '03-01-02-02-01-01-01_norm.wav'                                                                    fs, sig = scipy.io.wavfile.read(audio_path)                                                                                                                                                          lfcc  = lfcc(sig, 13)                                                                                                                  i have value error : negative dimensions are not allowed  because my sig array have negative values. Do you have a way to fix it? Thank you